# ¿Cómo mover un elemento de mi lista genérica en C#?

Tags: c#

LLeno mi lista de la siguiente manera:

```
List<string> list_empleados = new List<string>();                   
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select nombre from emp", conn);
SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    list_empleados.Add(dr[0].ToSAtring());
}
```

Me muestra los datos de la siguiente manera:

[image: Muestra]

¿Cómo puedo mover al usuario `Rastalovely` de la posición 4 a la primer posición quedando los demás en su posición?

Para que quede de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes quitar el elemento y colocarlo en la posicion que quieras:

**Update:** (gracias a la respuesta de Andrezi)

```
//con el if te aseguras de que estas insertando tras borrarlo
if( list_empleados.Remove("Rastalovely") )  
    list_empleados.Insert(0, "Rastalovely"); // 0  para mover al principio
```

Ten en cuenta que eliminará al primer elemento que coincida con ese string.

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias-...., pero existe una manera de copiar ese registro y después eliminarlo?

Comment: @Rastalovely A que te refieres con copiar? Puedes guardarlo en una variable

Comment: Si te refieres a que, en lugar del por nombre quieres hacerlo por posición, mira `RemoveAt(indice)`

Comment: Muchas Gracias a todos, he aceptado la respuesta como valida...

Answer (score 3):

```
List<string> list_empleados = new List<string>();                   
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select nombre from emp", conn);
SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    list_empleados.Add(dr[0].ToSAtring());
}

//Se utiliza el if para validar que efectivamente si se halla borrado el
//elemento, para poder insertarlo.

if(list_empleados.Remove("Rastalovely"))
    list_empleados.Insert(0, "Rastalovely");
```